# progress bar in script Python

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

I have to ask something that other guys did, but I haven't find an answer (maybe is stupid).

I need to implement a progress bar in my script python, ia red about tqdm and i like a lot that library because it has nice colours and the bar is well-structured, instead of a simple [---------].

a simple script that  I saw is this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
    pass
```

but my question is: **where do I insert my code??** seems stupid but I tried several times and the bar won't go. simply stays at 0% and until my script ends.

Another point is that if I try also that simple code, everytime the bar update itself, it creates a new line with a new bar. so how can I have a single bar that fill when time passes?

thanks a lot, and of course evry kind of support and advice will be appreciated

EDIT----
If my code is:

```
alphabetic = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0-9']

for lett in alphabetic: lista_pag_success = pr.find_following_page('/artisti/lettera/'+lett) 

artisti=[] 
linksss=[] 

for i in lista_pag_success: 
       artisti, linksss = pr.crawl_canzoni_it(i)
```

I have to put all this code in the tqdm() function? I have to pass just an iterable? but what if I have I case like this? lista_pag_success and artisti, linksss are three lists - this is a code for a simple crawler –

Comment: Which terminal are you using to run the code? Are you running in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: no man, I'm on Pycharm and instead of run the code I'm using che Python Console that is at the bottom on the left of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iterable over which you want to monitor progress, should replace `range(10000)` in the sample code you posted.

For example, if you have a list of numbers, `[1, 4, 9, 10]`, and you want to find the square of each number, you would iterate over `tqdm([1, 4, 9, 10])` and perform your calculation inside the `for` loop, i.e.:

```
squared_nums = []
for num in tqdm([1, 4, 9, 10]):
    squared_nums.append(num * num)
print(squared_nums)
```

This would generate output like:

```
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 4/4 [00:00<00:00, 14820.86it/s]
[1, 16, 81, 100]
```

Of course, in this simple case, it could also be written using a list comprehension:

```
squared_nums = [num * num for num in tqdm([1, 4, 9, 10])]
```

Comment: It depends on how you want to measure the progress. The easiest way would be to do `for lett in tqdm(alphabetic):`, then put the rest of your code inside the loop